# Why doesn't my code read in my input values?

Tags: c++, file, input, ifstream, cin

I'm coding in C++ and trying to make use of ifstream. This is the code:

```
int main()
{
    inFile.open("UserInfo.txt");
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
    }
    
    inFile >> init_check;
    if (init_check == "Y") {
        cout << "User Info found, press 1 if you would like to ignore the save data, otherwise save data will be loaded." << endl;
        cin >> useUserInfo;
        if (useUserInfo == "1") {
            initializer();
        }
        else {
            loadUserInfo();
        }
    }

    else {
        initializer();
    }
    
    
}
```

And this is the function loadUserInfo:

```
void loadUserInfo(){
    string none, goal;
    string FirstName, LastName, name;
    int age, height;
    char none1;
    float weight;
  
    inFile >> FirstName;
    getline(inFile, FirstName, ' ');
    getline(inFile, LastName);
    inFile >> age;
    inFile >> height;
    inFile >> weight;
    inFile >> goal;
    inFile.close();
    UserInfo main_user;
    main_user.SetUser(FirstName, LastName, height, weight, age, goal);
    
}
```

The file it reads from is perfectly fine and has the values. However, inFile doesn't read the values and instead reads in "" when I debug. What is the problem?

Comment: You will never know where it is failing until you learn to check the stream state following EVERY input, e.g. `if (!(inFile >> init_check)) { /* handle error */ }` and `if (!getline(inFile, Firstname, ' ')) { /* handle error */ }`. Also you fail to exit `if (!inFile) { ...`

Comment: When you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, and build up. If you overshoot, and find that your code doesn't work and the last version that worked was much simpler, backtrack to a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That usually makes the bug obvious, but if not, post it.